# android how to create multiple equal sized elements without linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout that contains 16 equally sized FrameLayout elements.  I've seen lots of replies about this and how "Nested layout weights are bad for performance."  What is a better way to solve this problem and still have the advantages of dynamic sizing of elements.
Thank you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mostly I just wanted to say thanks for the suggestions.  I spent a week or more trying to find a solution that worked and finally decided to go ahead with development and see what the performance was like.  The main problem was that I wanted the app to work on multiple devices and resize/handle orientation change and I couldn't find any suitable solution.
At this point everything is working.  In landscape mode I have 2 columns x 3 rows that contain 18 equal sized cells each with an image and frame.  Performance seems to be ok on everything I've tried from a cheap cell phone and generic 7" tablet up to a nexus-7.

Comment: Have you taught about using a TableLayout with TableRows?

Comment: Try to use GridLayout,how to use see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)? You might have to google a bit so figure out how you can make the items resize according to the screen width, but i think it's possible. `TableLayout` would work too, but `GridView` seems to be cleaner.

Comment: Hi @SimonSays.  GridView was my first try but I couldn't make it work.  I couldn't find any way to set the cell size and the googling I did seemed to say there was none.fact one of the replies I found said there is none.
I haven't used TableLayout before.  I'll look into it.
Thanks...

Comment: Have you looked at `stretchMode` in `GridView`? Setting it to `columnWidth` might do the trick. I'm not sure though. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode